# blender lagging only with sliders

Tags: customization

Blender seems to be running smoothly, but I am experiencing lag when I attempt to adjust the sliders of my rigged human mesh.

https://www.screencast.com/t/ZkR7tL44NlG

As you can see when i click/drag.. it freezes for a moment and then snaps to the correct size. But this makes it extremely difficult to test the mesh in all different sizes.

I also experience lag when the face count is too high but I figured that was normal?

I have a GeForce GTX 1060 6GB graphics card

Comment: Does your model have any subsurf? If so, you could toggle it off and that could help.

Comment: No subsurf, and I deleted all of the extra layers so that it would be less bogged down. My scene currently has 23k verts 31k faces 45k tris